# Why CreateNoWindow?

Tags: c#, .net

.NET's Process class has a property [`CreateNoWindow`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.createnowindow.aspx).

> #### ProcessStartInfo.CreateNoWindow Property
>
> Gets or sets a value indicating whether to start the process in a new window.

To me, that seems a queer choice of name for the property. The default is `CreateNoWindow = false`, a momentarily-confusing double negative.

Is there a reason the property is named as it is? Why not `CreateWindow` (with the opposite meaning)? Is there a rule that boolean properties must default to false?

Comment: "it forced me to write ..." - no, you **chose** to write the code. Since the *default* is `false`, your code is effectively an extended NOP.

Comment: Speculation: that's because `CreateNoWindow` is rarely needed. The default for it is `false`. When you're in a less usual case of not needing a window, you set this flag saying, I have this special case when I do not need a window. For all other cases you just ignore the flag, which reduces the overall amount of noise.

Comment: I think the OP has a point and no matter how rarely it is used, it could still have been called `CreateWindow` and have a default value of true.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever thanks good to know. I'll take that line out my code. Question edited.

Comment: This is one of those questions that can only really be answered by the person who wrote it (well, maybe also those who reviewed it). Any answer to this is likely to be pure speculation.

Comment: Note, that process creation in .NET is just a wrapper around a Win32 API function named `CreateProcess`. And one of the allowed flags for this function is `CREATE_NO_WINDOW`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I'd guess that it is simply a very literal reflection of the underlying Win32 [process creation flag](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684863.aspx) named `CREATE_NO_WINDOW`.

Only the author of the .net class can explain why the choice was made to reflect the Win32 convention onto the .net class. It could easily have been done the other way. If I had to guess, I'd suggest that the choice was made to make it very clear that the property maps directly onto `CREATE_NO_WINDOW`.

Comment: Cool that makes sense. So it's not a .NET standard or anything that boolean properties have to default to false.

Comment: Well, look at `UseShellExecute` from the very same class, which defaults to `true`.